# Qual a diferença entre exec(), system() e passthru()?

Tags: php

Quais as diferenças entre estas funções? Há alguma situação específica para usar cada função? Se existe, dê exemplos dessas situações.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Nessa](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/732832/php-exec-vs-system-vs-passthru) resposta do SO em inglês, é dito:

`exec()` - chama um comando do sistema, e você mesmo lida com o output

`system()` - executa um comando do sistema e mostra o output imediatamente (geralmente texto)

`passthru()` - executa um comando do sistema, do qual você quer o retorno "cru". Talvez em binário

Sugiro que não use nenhuma delas, já que gera código altamente não-portável.

***Documentação*** (em português)

Função [system](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.system.php)
Função [exec](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.exec.php)
Função [passthru](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.passthru.php)

Comment: Não entendi a frase "já que geral código altamente não-portável."

Comment: gera* hauahau, digitei errado